# Перетаскивание некого view поверх всех окон

Tags: android

В общем, хотят тут от меня такую штуку, а я даже не знаю, возможно ли такое сделать вообще.

Суть такова: Под таскбаром висит некая иконка, когда запущен сервис. Делаем по ней долгое нажатие - она становится подвижной. Двигаем к центру экрана - открывается само приложение.

Сейчас мне удалось повесить иконку и научить ее реагировать на нажатия.

Проблемы в следующем:
 - Если использовать тип окна `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`, то оно полюбому берет на себя все эветы. Как пропускать нажатия насквозь - непонятно.
 - Если использовать `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`, то он вообще не умеет ловить эвенты и все пропускает насквозь.

Как думаете, реально ли вообще что-то такое сделать? Сколько гуглил проги, которые работаю поверх всего, они обычно или некликабельные таблички с системной инфой (часы, системные показатели) или мелкие приложения в окошках.

Сейчас в сервисе вызываю окошко следующим образом:

```
private void Initialize(){

    this.frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    this.icon = new Button(this);
    //this.icon.setText("тест");
    this.icon.setClickable(true);
    this.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_status_bar_ligth);
    this.icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Log_tag", "Нажатие");

        }
    });

    this.icon.setLongClickable(true);
    this.icon.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showApp();
            Log.i("Log_tag", "Длинное нажатие");
            return true;
        }
    });

    frameLayout.addView(this.icon);

    this.WM = ((WindowManager)getSystemService("window"));

    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            40,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            );
    localLayoutParams.gravity = 51;

    this.WM.addView(this.frameLayout, localLayoutParams);
}
```

Comment: Решили забить на пропускание нажатий иконкой. Прикрутил обычный OnTouchListener к иконке и все норм. Только движение иконки за пальцем сделать нужно. Если есть у кого подобный пример - буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

[Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

> With the Android drag/drop framework, you can allow your users to move data from one View to another View in the current layout using a graphical drag and drop gesture. The framework includes a drag event class, drag listeners, and helper methods and classes.